# Open file in the context of the current Visual Studio Solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, user-controls

I am working on a project which supports arbitrary code in various forms (User Controls, custom Server Pages, etc.), so sometimes I will download or receive a file that I want to view or modify quickly. But, when this file does not reside within the Solution hierarchy, the syntax highlighting and Intellisense for the custom namespaces/classes I've created do not work and in fact show as errors.

So, how do I configure Visual Studio in such a way that any file I open will open in the context of the current Solution, as if I opened it in a subdirectory of the Project root folder?

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions of Windows, I worked around this by creating a symlink (with Windows's `mklink` command) within the Project folder to my download/temporary location, and then opening the files after navigating to them through the symlink.

Comment: With Windows 10, the same directory that would work with Windows 7 would cause VS to crash. Windows 10 probably parses Symlinks differently or probably more natively, so things like cyclical links will cause VS to loop infinitely. I never figured out why the original directory stopped working, but I targeted the link at a different location and Visual Studio worked with the new directory.